# Find the equation of the curves

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having trouble solving the following problem:

*Find the equation of the curves for which the length of the line segment of the normal, starting with a point on the curve and ending at the x-axis, is equal to **a**, where **a** is a constant.*

By expressing the x-coordinate of the point lying on the x-axis as
$ x_0 = y'y + x $ (using the fact that its slope is perpendicular to the one of the tangent, and plugging it into the equation for a line passing through a point), I obtain the following differential equation:
$$ y'^2 + 1 = \frac{a^2}{y^2} $$
The problem is that this form of a differential equation is unfamiliar to me, and I can't seem to find a way to solve it. I have tried substituting $ y' $ with $p$, but I didn't get far with that. I have also tried plugging it into some online differential equations calculators, but with no success.

I would be very grateful if someone could tell me whether I got the correct equation in the first place.

Comment: Can't you find $y'$ out of it?

Comment: HINT Equation okay,proceed further. Next $ \dfrac{y dy}{\sqrt{a^2-y^2}}=dx$ A semi-circle?

Comment: @Narasimham Thanks! It was the equation which made my uncertain for the most part so I didn't even think of separating the variables... Wouldn't I get a circle though?

Comment: @ivan-neretin You are right. I can. Thanks.